# Add public key to known_hosts file

Tags: linux, ssh, key

I am trying to copy a public key from Server A over to the known_hosts file in Server B. They are both linux servers. Initially I thought about opening the public key file and copying its contents over to the known_hosts file but I suspect that is not the correct method. Does anyone know what the right way to do so is?

My public key is in the format `ssh-rsa AADGD...`

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I answered almost similar answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1027613/differing-ssh-known-hosts-formats/1027678#1027678) few days ago. The important parts:

- The format differs
- There are different host keys (types) on each server (make sure you paste the one that is actually used)
- There is `ssh-keyscan` which can create the format for you

Otherwise just prefix your key with server IP address (you can add also hostname, after comma), remove the comment from end of the line and you are fine. Format then look like this:

```
11.22.33.44 ssh-rsa AADGD...
```

And one more note, if you use `HashKnownHosts yes` (Debian and Ubuntu does), you need to re-hash your `known_hosts` such as:

```
ssh-keygen -Hf ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thanks! So to confirm, I should edit the known_hosts file and add `server_ip_address ssh-rsa AADGD...` at the end of the file?

Comment: as I wrote. It should do the job.

Comment: gotcha, and is there a specific ip i should use? it typed `/sbin/ifconfig –a` and got about 5 different types of IP addresses.

Comment: the ip you want to use when connecting from `server B` to `server A` as your question describes. If it is somehow different, check the files and terms in the end of [`man sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)

Answer (score 18):

Having just bumped into this problem, here's how I approached it:

Over time, copying the files mechanically via

```
ssh-keyscan server-name >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

gave me duplicate entries in `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Other manual methods required me to create the `.ssh` directory didn't already exist, etc.

I decided to just let `ssh` handle it:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no server-name ls
```

The `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option automatically answers 'yes' to the

```
The authenticity of host 'server-name (12.345.678.900)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

message (insert here all the security caveats about connecting randomly to machines you don't know).

The `ls` command is just a fluff command that will execute and force SSH to disconnect when done.  You can change it to whatever fluff command you like.

ssh will take care of creating the `.ssh` dir (if necessary), adding only one copy of the key, etc.

Platform: macOS 10.14

Comment: And if I do not have a public Key on A? Will there be no ssh connection or is the key created on A and then pushed to `known_hosts`?

Comment: @Timo If you don't have your Public Key on the remote host already, you'll be prompted for a password.  I presume your local known_hosts will not be updated if your login fails, but I've not tested this.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I did it.

1. Generate a key on host server. Using the below command.

***ssh-keyscan -t rsa full-server-name**

[image: Command line and output]

2. Now copy the highlighted section(in the picture) and append this key to the ‘known_host’ file on source server. Of course, the location for this file could be different for different environments.

Comment: They provided a key, and hence probably wanted a solution *in terms of that key*, not keyscanning a server.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have a file called `publickey.pub` then please do this:

1. `scp` the `public key .pub` to your desired servers
2. Run for **AWS EC2 ubuntu** instances

```sh
sudo /bin/bash -c "cat /$USER_PATH/public_key.pub  >> $USER_PATH/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

3. for `known_hosts`= run

```sh
sudo /bin/bash -c "cat /$USER_PATH/public_key.pub  >> $USER_PATH/.ssh/known_hosts"
```

4. Test a connection with `ssh`

Note: make sure you check your public's key format. The ones I have seen up to this point begin with the encryption algorithm e.g. `ssh-RSA`

Comment: This does not work, if you append the .pub file on the known_hosts of the client it will be ignored.

Comment: perhaps is not an AWS EC2 instance ubuntu 18.04